# In Rails, app is erroneously throwing 404 page for a record with an ID of 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is erroneously throwing a 404 error page on the "show" action for a record with an ID of 404.

For example, /articles/1 works great, as well as /articles/403, and /articles/405, but /articles/404 is throwing a 404 page not found.

How can I fix this?

You'd be amazed at how hard it is to search this phenomenon without getting all kinds of other 404 related issues.

**Update**

The above route was oversimplified for ease of explanation. This issue was happening in a Shopify app. Basically for my Shopify admin routes, I am pulling up records with the ID at the base of the route. For example, I am having `https://example.myshopify.com/admin/apps/myapp/:id` show a record. However, this was proxied to `/:id` in my app, meaning `https://example.myshopify.com/admin/apps/myapp/404` was actually hitting `/404` in my app, which was ultimately hitting the `404.html` file in `/public`. Once I knew this, I was able to fix the route.

Comment: You'll need to explain your routes, and further, look *very* closely at your `log/development.log` output.

Comment: This is happening in production, and it isn't throwing anything into my production log. I guess next step will have to try to recreate it locally, just seemed like a very random _simple_ issue that I had trouble searching about, but had never happened to me before.

Comment: What's important is to identify the controller and action being executed. It's also important to try and reproduce it on your local dev machine.

Comment: @tadman figured out my issue, see update above.

Comment: Good find! Worth adding a self-answer like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, the above example route was oversimplified for ease of explanation. This issue was happening in a Shopify app. Basically for my Shopify admin routes, I am pulling up records with the ID at the base of the route. For example, I am having `https://example.myshopify.com/admin/apps/myapp/:id` show a record. However, this was proxied to `/:id` in my app, meaning `https://example.myshopify.com/admin/apps/myapp/404` was actually hitting `/404` in my app, which was ultimately hitting the `404.html` file in `/public`. Once I knew this, I was able to fix the route.